# child thread does not see effect of increment by main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I am working with a C networking application using POSIX threading. I encountered a problem where a child thread serving as a monitor not detecting the change (increment) to a global counter made by the main thread. I managed to extract the relevant code into the following 3 files and reproduce the problem.

```
// common.h
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
static volatile int glob = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void increment_clients_count();

#endif
```

```
// common.c
#include "common.h"

void increment_clients_count()
{
        // Lock
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);     
        glob++;
        // Unlock
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

```
// thread_incr_wrong.c 
// main function
#include "common.h"

void                    /* Loop 'arg' times incrementing 'glob' */
monitor()
{
    while(1)
    {        
        time_t current_time;
        time(&current_time);
        char *t = ctime(&current_time);
        if (t[strlen(t)-1] == '\n') t[strlen(t)-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s, Count : %d\n", t, glob);
        sleep(3);
    }

}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1;   
    int s;
   

    s = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (void*)monitor, NULL);
    if (s != 0){
        perror("pthread_create");
        exit(1);
     }
    
    while(1){        
        increment_clients_count();        
        sleep(5);
    }

    
    exit(0);
}
```

When this cod runs, I hope to see

```
Tue Jan 11 18:56:24 2022, Count : 1
Tue Jan 11 18:56:27 2022, Count : 1
Tue Jan 11 18:56:30 2022, Count : 2
Tue Jan 11 18:56:33 2022, Count : 2
Tue Jan 11 18:56:36 2022, Count : 3
Tue Jan 11 18:56:39 2022, Count : 4
Tue Jan 11 18:56:42 2022, Count : 4
Tue Jan 11 18:56:45 2022, Count : 5
Tue Jan 11 18:56:48 2022, Count : 5
Tue Jan 11 18:56:51 2022, Count : 6
Tue Jan 11 18:56:54 2022, Count : 7
```

Instead, the output looks like this

```
Tue Jan 11 18:59:40 2022, Count : 0
Tue Jan 11 18:59:43 2022, Count : 0
Tue Jan 11 18:59:46 2022, Count : 0
Tue Jan 11 18:59:49 2022, Count : 0
Tue Jan 11 18:59:52 2022, Count : 0
```

The monitor thread did not see `glob` variable being incremented every 5 seconds.

Please let me know where in the code I did something wrong.

If you'd like to try reproduce the problem, you can copy those 3 files and build the executable with
 `cc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -g -pedantic -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-sign-compare -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -o thread_incr_wrong  thread_incr_wrong.c common.c` on any Linux machine. The executable's name is **thread_incr_wrong**.

Thanks

Comment: Side note:  `monitor()` ought to acquire the mutex before reading the value of `glob` and release the mutex afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `glob` and `mutex` are declared as `static`.  This means that when common.h is included in both common.c and main.c, they each have their own copy of those variables.

Global variables should be *declared* in a header file where all source files can see them and *defined* in exactly one source file.  So change what's in the header to external declarations and put the definitions in common.c:

common.h:

```
extern volatile int glob;
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

common.c:

```
volatile int glob = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is the static declaration that is causing the error.

Comment: Note that the results would still be unpredictable because the result of accessing a `volatile int` from one thread while another thread might be modifying it are undefined by any of the standards involved.